# How can I remove rows with same elements in all columns of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` with the following elements:

```
> x[3536:3540,]
     V1 V2
3536  2  6
3537 13  6
3538  9  6
3539  6  6
3540  2  2
```

I want to remove rows with the same elements in all columns.
My desired result is as follows:

```
> x[3536:3540,]
     V1 V2
3536  2  6
3537 13  6
3538  9  6
```

I tried this:

```
x<-x[,1] != x[,2]
```

But I get only boolean values for each row, not matrix with rows with non-same elements in columns:

```
> x
   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [15] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [29] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [43] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [57] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [71] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [85] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
  [99] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [113] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subset/filter:

`Base R`:

```
x_new <- x[x$V1 != x$V2,]
```

`dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x_new <- x %>%
           filter(V1 != V2)
```

Result:

```
x_new
  V1 V2
2  1  2
3  1  3
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(1,1,1,1),
  V2 = c(1,2,3,1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below is assuming you want to subset within specific rows as per original post.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df <- df[3536:3540][V1 != V2]
```